# wrong IPA size in new iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store-connect, ipa

I just uploaded a new app for review on iTunes Connect ( new look ). The size of my ipa file is about 250MB.

After doing all the necessary steps with XCODE ( validating, distributing ) I find back my build and can select it for review.

However, the size of the IPA file on ITC is shown as 4.1MB.

I did not received any error message or 'Invalid Binary' mail during or after the validating and distributing process.

Is this a simple UI bug in iTunes Connect ( new version ) or is there more going on should I try to upload a new binary for review?

PS : I would have loved to add some images here but I'm a new StackOverflow member and not allowed yet to add these...

Comment: now I also meet the same issue, but i tried multiple times it show ing the same message in my knowledge no need of upload a new binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping it's just a bug.. like all the other bugs.
I never received an email saying the binary was invalid and when I click my build for more info, it says my binary has been validated.

Comment: It was indeed just a bug. The app got reviewed and is available in the store now :-)