# itunesconnect, App size after upload dosent make sense

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode6, application-loader

Ive uploaded an update for my App two days ago, it should be `9.0 MG`, but after submitting it it shows `1.11 MG`, so I've called [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php), they told me to do the following:

- Reject the current build and upload a new one `- Didn't work`
- Upload using `Xcode 5.1` instead of `Xcode 6 GM seed` `- Didn't work`
- Upload more than one build, and switch between them `- Didn't work`

So nothing worked with Apple, so they told that if I'm sure that I've uploaded the correct build to not worry, it might be a bug from the system.

Now ive uploaded an update for another app, and faced the same issue, the app size is `2.1` instead of `16.5`, so I've decided to use [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/Testflight/), its requires `iOS 8`, so I've updated my iPhone to iOS 8 beta, and once I've sent the link to the mobile, I've found that the app size is `2.1` !!, **And** every time i try to install the app, it says `EXPIRED`, so i didn't see the app working on the phone from the AppStore new build testing.

At the end, I've decided search on Google **again** for more results, "Ive tried to search about this issue 3-4 days ago but no results came", and found that some people got **Invalid Binary** after submitting the app "1-3 days", you can check these links: [Link 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6520010), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25737602/wrong-ipa-size-in-new-itunes-connect).

Nothing from what i found gave an accurate answer to this case.

**Anyone faced same issue?? what should i do??**

Comment: I have the same issue with the build for my new app on iTunes Connect. Whatever the method used (XCode 5.1, XCode 6 GM, Application Loader), it always shows a wrong binary size (7.2 MB instead of 29 MB). I am currently in the "Waiting for review" status and did not get "Invalid binary" message yet, hoping this is just a display bug with no consequence on real ipa consistency and usability. I did not find more answers nor related topics than you did on Google for now...

Comment: Hope that someone knows what is going on here

Comment: Hi, just thinking aloud: The binaries that you send to Apple are no longer usable by you, since they have been signed especially for Apple. I have not used the latest iTunes Connect for submitting apps, though. Since you ask what you should do, I would wait. Furthermore it looks like the longest time people waited till the invalid binary appeared was a couple of hours.

Comment: @lnjuanj these are good news, will wait till the app be in review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first app was approved by Apple and everything seems to be ok, the app size is now changed to the correct one "9.0" MB, and the app is working as expected on the device.

So its seems that the size issue is related to Apple, they have a bug on the itunesconnect.

So don't worry about the size issue anymore.

Comment: You should check your answer as the correct one - and possibly upvote my comment :)